# Log into a mac mini working as a server that is connected to a VPN

Tags: network, mac-mini, ssh, vpn

I have a Mac Mini (late 2014) that I want to connect to a VPN (for work), but I also want it to act as a server, so I can work from my laptop (running Linux). I basically need the Mac for the VPN and compiling some stuff.

Is it possible to have it connected to the VPN, but at the same time make an exception so I can connect to it from my local network?

Comment: What's the reason you can't connect to it now?  What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: I have no idea why, but I couldn't connect to it. I rebooted it and it worked. The Mac Mini is connected to the VPN and I can SSH to it from the LAN. Weird.